# ActiveX ComboBox to drive workbook formatting

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I would like to use an an ActiveX ComboBox to drive the formatting of the Excel workbook.

Particulars of relevance:

```
- ComboBox name: ComboBox1
- ComboBox options: Total, Products, Services
```

My macro thus far:

```
Sub ComboBox1_Change()
  Value = ComboBox1
  Case Total
  MsgBox "Total"
  Case Blank
  MsgBox "Products"
  Case Products
  MsgBox "Services"
  End Select
End Sub
```

To test it's working I have simply included the message display however this will be amended once all is running smoothly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know why it's all on the same row and very hard to read.. Sorry about that.

Comment: It seems you are missing a `Select Case`?

Comment: Yes, I thought so also.  I did include Select Case Value under Value = ComboBox1 but it didnt make a difference.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement

Comment: Thanks mate, but I'm just a lowly accountant so that blew my mind.  Essentially I think I need to define my drop down items in the Select list.  Let's start simple.  Is Select Case Value a true statement?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to do something like this:

```
Sub ComboBox1_Change()
  Select Case ComboBox1.Value
    Case "Total"
      MsgBox "Total"
    Case "Blank"
      MsgBox "Products"
    Case "Products"
      MsgBox "Services"
  End Select
End Sub
```

Does that meet your needs?

Comment: Thanks.  Now on the first Total I receive an error "Compile error: Expected Function or variable"

Comment: Let's start from the start.    I create a drop down list using the Combo Box (ActiveX Control) option.  Excel then provides this list a name such as ComboBox1 and it is this name I use when entering "Select Case ComboBox1.Value"?